# AAD Security Group Question Technical Question

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365

I have currently 2 technicians under me and I am looking how I can control their access without giving them too much right.

We normally control the access to different SharePoint trough Security Group. We created AAD Security Group for each department and we give access to each SharePoint this way.

We have 1 SharePoint for HR that have 3 different AAD Security Group giving different level of access on this SharePoint.

The problem is, my 2 techs should not be able to access this SharePoint, but because they have access right to all AAD Groups via different Roles they can give themselves the access.

I looked at a bunch of solution like creating a custom role, but many resources cannot be added.

Do you have a possible solution to block them to be able to access? Like a Deny of the SharePoint or on a group.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

IT staff with administrative access have always had the possibility to access protected resources that THEY configure and provide access to.

Therefore, the solution to this problem is not with technology, but with people management. One approach is to

- let IT staff sign an agreement that they don't attempt to access specific sites (this may already be covered in their employment contract in some obscure clause)
- use audit reports to monitor access to these sites. The security auditor is of course another IT person, so there is some level of trust involved.
- follow through on breaches with immediate penalties that serve as deterrents to others.